Is pooling on newly paved asphalt driveway a problem?
48 hours ago my driveway was paved. 12 hours after it was laid there was a steady amount of rain for about 6 hours. It was dry for 24 hours and then rained steady for 30 mins. After both rainfalls there were a couple of areas where water has pooled (same areas). Once rain stopped, the water cleared up pretty quickly but it didn' flow down a slope, it just disappeared.
Is this something I should be worried about? My contractor says it's normal for it to be absorbed into the asphalt and then into the hard-core underneath.
Just to clarify, there are 2 standout pools of water and lots of little pools of water when raining.

Please post photos

You will get pooling if the driveway isn't flat.  Is this fresh asphalt?

Whether you should be worried isn't for us to decide. Please revise to ask something more specific and objective.

Welcome. Please take the [tour].

Your local codes should dictate a minimum slope to paved areas to ensure that pooling does not occur. This is especially important if you live in an area where temperatures drop below freezing.
